# Elixir / Elixir-mongo collection find breaks on Enum.to_list

Tags: mongodb, elixir

This is my first go around with elixir, and I'm trying to make a simple web scraper that saves into mongodb.

I've installed the elixir-mongo package and am able to insert into the database correctly. Sadly, I'm not able to retrieve the values that I have put into the DB.

Here is the error that I am getting:

```
** (Mix) Could not start application jobboard: exited in: JB.start(:normal, [])
** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
    ** (ArgumentError) argument error
        (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1266: Enum.reduce/3
        (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1798: Enum.to_list/1
        (jobboard) lib/scraper.ex:8: JB.Scraper.scrape/0
        (jobboard) lib/jobboard.ex:26: JB.start/2
        (kernel) application_master.erl:272: :application_master.start_it_old/4
```

If I understand the source correctly, then the mongo library should implement reduce here:

https://github.com/checkiz/elixir-mongo/blob/13211a0c0c9bb5fed29dd2faf7a01342b4e97eb4/lib/mongo_find.ex#L78

Here are the relevant sections of my code:

```
#JB.Scraper

def scrape do
  urls = JB.ScrapedUrls.unscraped_urls
end



#JB.ScrapedUrls

def unscraped_urls do
  MongoService.find(%{scraped: false})
end



#MongoService

def find(statement) do
  collection |> Mongo.Collection.find(statement) |> Enum.to_list
end

defp collection do
  mongo = Mongo.connect!
  db = mongo |> Mongo.db("simply_hired_urls")
  db |> Mongo.Db.collection("urls")
end
```

As a bonus, if anyone can tell me how I can get around connecting to Mongo every time I make a new call, that would be awesome. :) I'm still figuring out FP.

Thanks!
Jon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Didn't use this library, but I just made a simple attempt of the simplified version of your code.

I've started with

```
Mongo.connect!
|> Mongo.db("test")
|> Mongo.Db.collection("foo")
|> Mongo.Collection.find(%{scraped: true})
|> Enum.to_list
```

This worked fine. Then I suspected that the problem occurs when too many connections are open, so I ran this test repeatedly, and then it failed with the same error you got. It failed consistently when trying to open the connection for the 2037th time. Looking at the `mongodb` log, I can tell that it can't open another connection:

```
[initandlisten] can't create new thread, closing connection
```

To fix this, I simply closed the connection after I converted the results to list, using `Mongo.Server.close/1`. That fixed the problem

As you detect yourself, this is not an optimal way of communicating with the database, and you'd be better off if you could reuse the connection for multiple queries.

A standard way of doing this is to hold on to the connection in a process, such as `GenServer` or an `Agent`. The connection becomes a part of the process state, and you can run multiple queries in that process over the same connection.

Obviously, if multiple client processes use a single database process, all queries will be serialized, and the database process then becomes a performance bottleneck. To deal with this, you could open a pool of processes, each one managing a distinct database connection. This can be done in simple way with the [poolboy library](https://github.com/devinus/poolboy).

My suggestion is that you try implementing a single `GenServer` based process that maintains the connection and runs queries. Then see if your code works correctly, and when it does, try to use `poolboy` to be able to deal with concurrent requests efficiently.

Comment: sasajuric, Thanks for being so thorough! I imagine that is the error. I'm going to take a look at it and get back to you.